# Restore Unity to Default

Tags: unity, elementary

I recently installed Elementary OS onto Ubuntu 16.10 using the steps in [the accepted answer to “How can I install elementary OS on Ubuntu?”](/a/48163/175814). As a result, the window border for unity now looks different:

[image]

The window border now has a "squeezed" design. Specifically, the top left buttons (close, minimize, maximize) being more separated than normal, and the window bar has been decreased in height. After removing elementary os entirely, unity remains this way. Is there a way I can go back to the original design?

**Note:** The solution “[How do I reset my Unity configuration?](/q/17610)” is no longer effective.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed elementary os onto ubuntu"? What exactly did you install? As such, your question isn't clear.

Comment: Whoops... there. I put a link in my question to how I installed it, as well as what it is.

Comment: Okay, so you want to restore Unity. So not off-topic. I retracted my vote to close.

Comment: It may be... but the answer doesn't work, due to the flag needed being depreciated :/

Comment: It's unclear from the your question which of the answers "these steps" you followed.

Comment: Ok, I made the above more clear. (which answer I used)

Comment: Ok. Just so I'm completely clear are you attempting to install Elementary OS as stated in your question or the "elementary-desktop package" indicated by the solution you tried?

Comment: You may have noticed that the accepted solution to resetting unity configuration is for 12.04 and older. Please [edit] which release you are using into your question. It would also be helpful (at least for me)  if you could define "squeezed design"

Comment: Gotcha. Those edits described above have been saved into the question. :) Also yes, you are correct regarding which package I installed.